# Display the uploaded file name via Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, file-upload

I have the following HTML / JS code:

```
<div class="file_upload">
        <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" onchange="g();">
    </div>
<script>
    function g() {
        var fileName = document.getElementById("file_upload").value;
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        alert(fileName);
    }
</script>
```

I want that after user upload a file, than the file name will displlay in alert the problem in this cide is that the path & the file name are diplayed and I want the file name only.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How does the path look like? You're searching for "/" but in Windows, for example, you have to search for "\".

Comment: Most likely you're testing on Windows and since the substring uses `/` to split off the filename, it won't match `\\`. Quick solution would be: fileName = fileName.replace('\\', '/').substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var fnSplit = fileName.split(/[\/\\]/);
fileName = fnSplit[fnSplit.length - 1];
```

The path separator may be different with different OSes (for example, Windows and Linux), so you have to search for all of them. The most commons are `/` and `\`, and a simple regular expression can do the trick.